# Getting code from my forked repository

Tags: git, laravel, repository, laravel-5, composer-php

I made a fork from a repository called **"chrisbjr/api-guard"**. the repository  latest version is **v2.2.2**, and I made a release **v2.2.3** from my fork.

I have my own branch which is dev-fulluth, to get the code from my fork not from the main repo, composer has to contain the below code:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/Yunishawash/api-guard"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "chrisbjr/api-guard": "dev-fullauth",
        "lootils/geo": "*",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
    },
```

but when I apply composer update, the code is pulled from the main repository

can any one help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at your repository in `https://github.com/Yunishawash/api-guard` it looks like it doesn't have a branch called `dev-fullauth`.

Instead there is a branch `dev-bugfix`. But you **must not** name your branch including the `dev-` prefix. Rename your branch at github from `dev-bugfix` to `bugfix` and then your `require` section would look like this:

```json
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "chrisbjr/api-guard": "dev-bugfix",
    "lootils/geo": "*",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
},
```

**Note:** If you don't rename your branch your requirement would be `"chrisbjr/api-guard": "dev-dev-bugfix",`.